# Meaning of Registry returned 403 for PUT

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I am trying to add  new tag to my package's dist-tags. At first I get the warning, I get `Registry returned 403`. Why is this happening? What can I do to add `a_new_tag` to the dist-tags?

```
$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "@kilojoules/tutorial_npm",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "thefieldentry"
  },
  "description": "for the tutorial!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node test.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@linclark/pkg": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}


$ npm dist-tag add @kilojoules/tutorial_npm@1.0.5 a_new_tag
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-c9
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/npm" "dist-tag" "add" "@kilojoules/tutorial_npm@1.0.5" "a_new_tag"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code E403

npm ERR! Registry returned 403 for PUT on http://localhost:15443/-/package/@kilojoules%2ftutorial_npm/dist-tags/a_new_tag
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/tutorial_npm/npm-debug.log
kilojoules:~/workspace/tutorial_npm (master) $ npm dist-tag add @kilojoules/tutorial_npm@1.0.5 a_new_tag
npm WARN dist-tag add a_new_tag is already set to version 1.0.5

$ npm dist-tag add @kilojoules/tutorial_npm@1.0.5 newTag
npm WARN dist-tag add newTag is already set to version 1.0.5

# where are the tags?
$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "@kilojoules/tutorial_npm",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "thefieldentry"
  },
  "description": "for the tutorial!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node test.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@linclark/pkg": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/issues/758

Comment: To those who come across this problem - start over. You made a mistake somewhere along the way.